# Dask groupby index column

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I'm loading in a large number of csv files (several thousand) from s3 into dask using `dd.read_csv(s3://bucket/*)`. These files have an implied index column (an unnamed column in ascending order):

[image: Example ddf with implied index column]

Is there a way to use the ddf.groupby() operation in order to group the csv files by the index value? My ultimate goal is to calculate an average value for each cell whileI've been struggling to find an answer online. I've tried using something like groupby(axis=0) and groupby(level=0) but that returns an error in dask.

My only other thought is to instead load the files using a for loop through the directory and manually add a new index column explicitly--but this seems like an unnecessarily expensive operation.

Comment: Do you mean that you would like the mean value of all of the row-0s, all of the row-1s, and so on, from the many files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I notice that your columns are named with values.  I recommend something like the following to tell pandas that there are no headers in your files.

```
df = dd.read_csv(..., header=None)
```

Then you should be able to groupby the appropriate column.  For example if the zeroth column holds your implicit index then you might compute the average of some other columns with code like the following:

```
df.groupby(0)[[1, 3, 5].mean().compute()
```

Comment: the header=None was exactly the step I was missing. Thanks!